# Get file(word, excel, ppt) metadata information in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, client

I would like to get information on file, at least only the information on number of pages from nodejs in client side (react). I was able to get the same for PDF files using PDFJs. Could someone point as to how it can be done for other file types like word, xls and ppt ? If there are external APIs which would provide this service, pointing that would be helpful too.

Comment: Which kind of "meta" are you hoping to get, besides number of pages?

Comment: Number of pages information would suffice

Answer (score 1):

For getting page count in docx and pdf files you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-pdf-pagecount

```
const getPageCount = require('docx-pdf-pagecount');

getPageCount('E:/sample/document/aa/test.docx')
  .then(pages => {
    console.log(pages);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });


getPageCount('E:/sample/document/vb.pdf')
  .then(pages => {
    console.log(pages);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XLSX](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) to parse spreadsheet-like files. XLSX can parse the files and return all the info of them.

But you can only retrieve the meta info until you use XLSX to parse those files. That means, no matter what, you have to parse them. If your files are big, it would be a performance issue for client browsers if you do it on client slide.

#### Update:

A hint, you can find some tools to detect the file type of the files, and deliver them to the corresponding parser the get the meta info.

For now, there is no such library implemented natively in JavaScript. If you are fine with some other none-pure node modules.

Like [textract](https://github.com/dbashford/textract), see how it works.

Comment: Would xlsx work with file types other than spreadsheets? Like MS Word or Powerpoint files ?

Comment: I'm sorry, This is only for spreadsheet. I miswrote something.

Comment: Getting file type is not a problem. I have that available. I am using dropzone to fetch the files.

Comment: dropzone is only for receiving the file. I don't think it can detect the file types?